# Linux Mint suicides on my PC

Tags: linux-mint, bootloader

I installed Linux Mint 18 KDE on my desktop PC. It worked properly for around a day and next time I boot into my PC it shows a message

> unable to boot from hd0

Every time this happens I have to boot from pendrive and install it again. I did that for 3 times now. Please help. I use Intel DH61BF motherboard.

Comment: Have you scanned the disk for errors?

Comment: Try repairing GRUB: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the same motherboard and got the same problem. Don't know the cause but I came up with a solution. I installed my system on a 32GB Sandisk Ultra.

Things I did: 
1. mount point "/" on the pendrive 
2. /home in a 250 GB HDD partition 
3. 5GB SWAP in HDD 
4. 2GB efi partition in HDD 
5. Bootloader in HDD

This will be enough for install.

Any doubts please ask.

Answer (score 0):

Start pc with live cd / usb and run

grub-install /dev/hda

hda = your hard disk

maybe you have proble with grub